# preg_match doesn't work in .php file with UTF-8 encoding

Tags: php, validation, email, utf-8, preg-match

Can somebody explain me how it works?After half hour of thinking what can cause problems with PHP function preg_match I found that file encoding is source of my worries.Giving You example from website:

```
function  checkEmail($email) {
if (!preg_match("/^( [a-zA-Z0-9] )+( [a-zA-Z0-9\._-] )*@( [a-zA-Z0-9_-] )+( [a-zA-Z0-9\._-] +)+$/" , $email)) {
return false;
}
return true;
};
```

Function presented above is correct in 100%.I pasted it into my file to just check if my function is wrong but my function and that one above both don't work when UTF-8 enabled and work properly when ANSI enabled.Can You exactly explain where problem is or what mistake I'm doing.Thank You.

Comment: Very useful section @chris85.Works perfectly.Thanks for Your help. :) BTW I've never did meet that PHP section. :D

Comment: Glad to help, posted answer below. In case future users encounter similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell it the search subject is UTF8.

```
function  checkEmail($email) {
    if (!preg_match("/^( [a-zA-Z0-9] )+( [a-zA-Z0-9\._-] )*@( [a-zA-Z0-9_-] )+( [a-zA-Z0-9\._-] +)+$/u" , $email)) {
          return false;
    }
          return true;
}
```

In that regex I added the `u` at the end which makes the pattern and the string utf8.

> Pattern and subject strings are treated as UTF-8.

-[Full documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) (and other modifiers)